# Como armazenar imagens no Parse?

Tags: android, parse, parse.com

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como salvar imagens num banco Parse. 
No Firebase é possivel salvar o caminho da imagem e deixá-la no Storage do Google. Já no Parse não consegui encontrar se tem como salvar apenas o caminho da imagem ao invés de salvar a própria imagem convertida no banco (exemplos que encontrei convertem a imagem e salvam).

Alguém sabe como fazer e se é possível?